# macOS Catalina 上で System Integrity Protection を有効にしたまま USB 通信をキャプチャすることはできますか？

Tags: macos, usb, wireshark

macOS Catalina 上で USB 通信のパケットキャプチャを行いたいです。

Wireshark を使って行おうとしたのですが、System Integrity Protection （以下 SIP）を無効にしないとキャプチャが行えないようでした。実際 The Wireshark Wiki には次のように書かれています。

> In macOS Catalina, you apparently have to disable System Integrity Protection to capture USB traffic.

https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB#macOS

英語版 Stack Overflow にも類似の質問があったのですが、こちらでも現状は `csrutil` コマンドで SIP を無効にする方法のみが紹介されていました：https://stackoverflow.com/a/59149241/5989200。

Wireshark の関係する部分については SIP を無効化するのもしょうがないかなと思わないでもないのですが、単に SIP を完全に無効化してしまうと Wireshark の関係ないところでも無効化されてしまうので、セキュリティ観点で不安があります。

キャプチャ用の端末をもうひとつ用意して、そちらをインセキュアな環境として運用することも考えられますが、利便性のためになるべく開発環境と同じ端末を使いたいため、これは最終手段としたいです。同様に、Windows 10 上では Wireshark でキャプチャできることを確認済みですが、開発用の端末でキャプチャまで行いたいため Mac を使いたいです。

可能な限りセキュリティ機構は無効化せずにキャプチャを行いたいのですが、SIP を無効にせずにキャプチャする方法は無いでしょうか？

Comment: USB プロトコルアナライザを使うのが面倒が無くていいと思うっス。いまどきそんなに高価ではなくなってきてるし。

Comment: なるほど、ハードウェアで解決するということですね。確かに手段のひとつとしてアリですね……。